# Can high school cheating hurt me for grad admissions?

Tags: cheating

I used to be a dumb cheater in high school. I was pretty smart but I still was cheating on things like dual credit courses at local colleges, and even AP exams. I ended up getting into a pretty good college. I felt pretty bad and since I've entered undergrad I haven't ever cheated, and I've been 100% honest. But I still feel pretty bad about what I did, and I'm scared it might hurt for graduate admissions. Is it possible that high school cheating can hurt me for grad admissions if it was in a college course? Also, if my high school diploma ever did get revoked, would my college degree get revoked as well?

Comment: Related: [What are the criteria for degree revocation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/what-are-the-criteria-for-degree-revocation)

Comment: @cag51 one of the criterion listed in the post you linked is admissions fraud. could what i did possibly be labelled as admissions fraud? i am going to a decently prestigious college, though I don't believe that cheating is what got me in

Comment: As the linked answer says, it is impossible to say how any individual case might be handled. But the odds that your high school detects cheating years later, prosecutes you for it, revokes your degree, your college finds out, they revoke your acceptance....no one can guarantee it won't happen, but I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102175/cheated-on-an-exam-when-i-was-eight-years-old-should-i-tell-graduate-admissions

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I am now super curious *how* you cheated in high school so that you worry years later about your degree getting revoked. If I think about HS cheating I think of copied homework and glancing to your neighbour during an exam, but I assume you did something a bit more ... industrious?

Comment: @xLeitix mostly stuff like using chegg on tests, as well as texting my friends during AP exams when they were online. stuff that leaves an online footprint. that's why it scares me a little bit

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely, but it might depend on where you are. In the US if you graduate from a program disciplinary actions aren't revealed except in extraordinary cases (court orders). You don't even mention whether you were disciplined.

If your transcript shows failed courses then you might be asked about it for university admissions, but for grad school the distant past remains buried.

If you aren't prone to cheating now, you will probably be fine. But if you are ever expelled from a program for dishonesty it would probably haunt you.

Comment: what do you mean "if you are ever expelled from a program for dishonesty it would probably haunt you"??

Comment: It is possible to be kicked out of college for some infractions. That stays on your record and grad schools ask for all transcripts of all undergraduate programs, not just the successful ones. (US, at least). If you were expelled from a HS, but got into college then you probably don't need to worry about the HS issues. (probably)

Comment: nah, i never got in trouble for cheating. i graduated fine. however I'm just a little paranoid that since I took college classes and got some credit for them I could get in trouble for cheating in those classes, although it was only a little

Comment: Generally people are more interested in your current record than in the past. Especially the long past. Relax.

Comment: Learning to repent of sins committed when young is a healthy snd normal part of growing up. Forget about it. Look ahead, not back.